# Defining selected option of html form in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple html form with select element. To define which option is selected, I add `selected` as

```
<option value="10" <?php if($value == '10') {echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>10</option>
<option value="20" <?php if($value == '20') {echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>20</option>
<option value="50" <?php if($value == '50') {echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>50</option>
```

`$value` is a variable which comes from PHP codes. This methods seems to be very simple and naive. Is it the best way to do so?

Comment: You'd better loop through all options, and create the `<option>` elements on the fly. Less code, more readable, easier to maintain.

Comment: Write a function for it. You're going to write form inputs a zillion more times.

Comment: Or even better, use a form engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a bad way to do it. But why not create the entire thing using programmatic approach (i.e., generate the code using a PHP loop through an array):

```
$items = array(10, 20, 50);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i ++) {
    echo("<option value='" . $items[$i] . "'");
    if ($items[$i] === $value) {
        echo(" selected='selected'");
    }
    echo(">" . $items[$i] . "</option>");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$options = array(10,20,50);
foreach($options as $option) {
    $selected = ($value == $option) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '<option value="' . $option . '"' . $selected . '>' . $option . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Looks like somebody has been systematically downvoting every answer to this question without comment

Comment: Agreed. What's the matter with people?

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of the below should work:

```
<?
$values = array(10, 20, 30);

foreach ($values as $val) {
?>
<option value="<?=$val?>" <?=($value==$val ? "SELECTED" : "")?>><?=$val?></option>
<?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your values in an array and loop over it to generate the HTML. Then you don't need to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($list as $key => $value): ?>

    <option value=<?php echo $value ?> <?php echo $value == $selected? 'selected' : '' ?> ><?php echo $value ?></option>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Would be cleaner if you separated the presentation from the logic. It's been years since PHP was introduced as a template engine.

Comment: While I agree that a templating engine would be the best approach, I think this solution is simpler, clearer and more maintainable than having a function that vomits html and much more straightforward than having to learn a template engine

Answer (score 0):

This is the like i do it:

```
      <?
    $values = array(10,20,30,......);
$value = XXX;

echo "<select name='somename'>";

foreach($values as $v)
{
if($v == $value)
{
echo "<option value='$v' 'selected'>$v </option>";

}
else
{
echo "<option value='$v'>$v </ option> ";
}


}
echo "</select>";

    ?>
```